# PostConstruct methos called again with richfaces 4.2 , works fine with myfaces

Tags: jsf

I am seeing different behaviors of  and  in a page containing multiple forms.

Here is my backing bean:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MultiFormBean
{
    String inputText1 = "";
    String inputText2 = "";

    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeBean(){
        System.out.println("PostConstruct Called ------------------");
    }

    public String getInputText1()
    {
        return inputText1;
    }

    public void setInputText1(String inputText1)
    {
        this.inputText1 = inputText1;
    }

    public String getInputText2()
    {
        return inputText2;
    }

    public void setInputText2(String inputText2)
    {
        this.inputText2 = inputText2;
    }

    public void doSubmit1() {
        inputText2 = inputText1;
    }

    public void doSubmit2() {
        inputText1 = inputText2;
    }

}
```

When i use the following xhtml , clicking Submit1 and Submit2 any number of times won't call @PostConstruct more than once:

```
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="firstForm" prependId="false">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="renderTarget1"/>
            <h:inputText id="first_input" value="#{multiFormBean.inputText1}"/>
            <h:commandButton id="click1" action="#{multiFormBean.doSubmit1}" value="submit1" type="submit"
                             onclick="javascript:jsf.ajax.request(this, event, {execute:'firstForm', render:'renderTarget1 secondForm'}); return false;">
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
        <h:form id="secondForm" prependId="false">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="renderTarget2"/>
            <h:inputText id="second_input" value="#{multiFormBean.inputText2}"/>
            <h:commandButton id="click2" action="#{multiFormBean.doSubmit2}" value="submit2" type="submit"
                             onclick="javascript:jsf.ajax.request(this, event, {execute:'secondForm', render:'renderTarget2 firstForm'}); return false;">

            </h:commandButton>

        </h:form>       
</h:body>
```

But the following xhtml would call @PostConstruct more than once:

```
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="firstForm" prependId="false">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="renderTarget1"/>
            <h:inputText id="first_input" value="#{multiFormBean.inputText1}"/>
<a4j:commandButton id="click1" action="#{multiFormBean.doSubmit1}" value="submit1" type="submit" execute="@form" render="renderTarget1,secondForm"/>
        </h:form>
        <h:form id="secondForm" prependId="false">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="renderTarget2"/>
            <h:inputText id="second_input" value="#{multiFormBean.inputText2}"/>

            <a4j:commandButton id="click2" action="#{multiFormBean.doSubmit2}" value="submit2" type="submit" execute="@form" render="renderTarget2,firstForm"/> 


        </h:form>       
    </h:body>
```

Please can anyone help me use the `<a4j:commandButton>` instead of `<h:commandButton>`

Also i see that i cannot call the method `doSubmit2()` with a4j commandButton

Comment: Also i see that i cannot call the method doSubmit2() with a4j commandButton

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem here is in bug inside JSF2 and Richfaces4. From 4 version Richfaces started using JSF embedded ajax capabilities. And There is a bug with using multiple forms on page with ajax requests. The problem there that richfaces renders special hidden input with the id of currently rendered view state. This id is changed when new view is rendered. And it is also submitted with every request to show that it belongs to some specific view. So when you have multiple forms on the same page after first ajax request the view state is getting the wrong place and it can be not submitted again second time. Sometimes behavior looks like very very wierd with no logical description.

PostConstruct is called twice because server thinks that two requests belong to different views(view state is not sumbitted) and as far as bean is view scoped it is created twice. After clicking aroung ajax can completelly stop working with this because server woukd not recognize the view(probably what you see when you can not click second submit button).

In the first place I recommend you to use latest available version of JSF and Richfaces. This bug (and many more) may be already fixed there.